# Searching through JSON Object with ng-disabled (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, json

One of the features of my web application is the possibility to add new users (username + password) through a form. Thereby, I have one JSON object (`l_usernames`) defined in a controller (`UsersController`) with all the usernames already chosen by users to avoid the repetition of usernames (it's a unique key).

**Sample of my data (fetched-data.json) - format of object "usernames" (`l_usernames`):**

```
[{"0":"default","USERNAME":"default"},{"0":"user1","USERNAME":"user1"},{"0":"user2","USERNAME":"user2"},{"0":"user3","USERNAME":"user3"}]
```

**There is a sample of the form to add new users (add-user.html):**

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="UsersController">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Add New User</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUserUsername" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="icon fa fa-user"></i> USERNAME</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputUserUsername" placeholder="Username" ng-model="user_username">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="inputUserPassword" class="col-sm-2 control-label"><i class="icon fa fa-key"></i> PASSWORD</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputUserPassword" placeholder="Password" ng-model="user_password">
            </div>
          </div>  
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <div class="span7 text-center">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addUser()" ng-disabled="(!user_username || !user_password)">Save</button>    
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Sample of my controller (userscontroller.js):**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp');

app.controller('UsersController', ['$scope', 'services', function($scope, services) {     

services.getData().then(function(data){
  $scope.l_usernames = data.data;
});
}])

.factory('services', ['$http', function($http){
  var serviceBase = 'services/'
  var object = {};
  object.getData = function(){
    return $http.get('fetched-data.json');
  };
  return object;
}]);
```

I would like to know how it is possible to not allow the insert of new users if the username is already chosen - searching through the JSON object `l_usernames` - with ng-disabled (by disabling the "Save" button). I also want to print a simple message - "Username already chosen" - if such situation occurs. Thank you.

Comment: You could create a directive to check if the value of the input already exists in your json and set the input validation accordingly. Then you simply disable the button if the form is invalid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a watch on the user_username scope variable. Whenever it changes search through the JSON object, you can use lodash or underscorejs to search through l_usernames to see if the username already exists. If it exists then set a variable in the scope to *false*. Bind the ng-disabled of the save button to this variable. Use debounce on the user_username for better performance.

Take a look at this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/pratikjs/voyphzw2/3/)

**Controller**

```
function UsersController($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.l_username = [{"0":"default","USERNAME":"default"},{"0":"user1","USERNAME":"user1"},{"0":"user2","USERNAME":"user2"},{"0":"user3","USERNAME":"user3"}];
    $scope.allowSave = true;
    $scope.$watch('user_username', function(value) {
      if (_.findWhere($scope.l_username, {"USERNAME": value}) !== undefined)
         $scope.allowSave = false;
         else
         $scope.allowSave = true;
    })
}
```

**HTML**

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" ng-click="addUser()" ng-disabled="!allowSave">Save</button>
```

Whenever the entered username is found in the array, the *allowSave* variable is changed which disables the 'save' button.

Note: I have used underscore.js to search through the list. You can use you custom method as well.

I have added the warning message and debounced the model for better performance.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will edit my post to add more information about how I fetched my data.

Comment: Once you get the l_usernames array, the above code should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would make a validation directive.

**HTML:**

```
<input username-exists type="text" ng-model="userName" ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 700, 'blur': 0 }}" />
<div ng-if="myFormName.$error.usernameExists">Username exists!</div>

<button type="button" ng-disabled="myFormName.$invalid">
```

The `ng-model-options` is so that your model doesn't go crazy and update always (it delays the validation).

**Javascript:**

```
app.directive('usernameExists', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A', //match attributes only
        require: 'ngModel',
        scope: {
            l_usernames: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
                //first, assume the model is valid until proven otherwise
                ctrl.$setValidity('usernameExists', true);

                if(viewValue.length > 0 && !ctrl.$error.usernameExists) {

                    for(var i = 0; i < scope.l_usernames.length; ++i) {
                        if(scope.l_usernames[i].USERNAME === viewValue) {
                            //username exists, so set valididty to false
                            //the form is not valid
                            ctrl.$setValidity('usernameExists', false);
                            break; //found match
                        }
                    }
                }

                return viewValue;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems to be a good solution to my problem but I already implemented an another one. Cheers!